# Check if a cell's value is in another cell's list/set

Tags: pandas, vectorization

If I have the following DataFrame:

```
      country       countries
1      France       {France, Sweden, England}
2     Germany       {France, Sweden, England}
3     Germany       {Portugal, Greece, Germany}
4      Sweden       {Spain, England}
5       Spain       {England, Greece}
6       Spain       {Portugal, Spain, Italy}
```

Is there a fast (vectorised) way of checking if `country` is in the set of `countries`?

```
      country       countries                         is_in
1      France       {France, Sweden, England}         True
2     Germany       {France, Sweden, England}         False
3     Germany       {Portugal, Greece, Germany}       True
4      Sweden       {Spain, England}                  False
5       Spain       {England, Greece}                 False
6       Spain       {Portugal, Spain, Italy}          True
```

Doing that with `df.apply()` is very easy but also extremely slow. Therefore, I'm looking for a solution using either Numpy or native Pandas vectorised methods.

I thought about Numpy's `np.isin()` or `np.in1d()` but they don't fit, because they assume a unique, constant set of values to compare against, instead of one set of values per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use set intersection

```
df.country.transform(lambda s: {s}) & df.countries.values
```

Check timings

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000)

%timeit df.country.transform(lambda s: {s}) & df.countries.values
4.53 ms ± 512 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x['country'] in x['countries'], 1)
156 ms ± 6.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit [x in y for x , y in zip(df.country,df.countries)]
598 µs ± 97.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
[x in y for x , y in zip(df.country,df.countries)]
```

Comment: Just tried and got a `TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable`

Comment: @Jivan that error doesn't make sense, unless `df.countries` has `np.nan`

Comment: Yep, it actually does

Comment: Then check for null/nan `[x in y if not pd.isnull(y) else False for x , y in zip(df.country,df.countries)]` (or fill the nans with something)

Comment: or `zip(df.country,df.countries.fillna(''))` ?

Comment: Maybe.. but filling `''` will yield True if `''` is also in country in the same row. using `pd.isnull` yields False (just a matter of checking how you want the output to be !)

Answer (score 0):

If you could change those curly braces to square ones, df.iterrows() can be used

`df["is_in"] = [row["country"] in row["countries"] for idx, row in df.iterrows()]`

I don't know if this satisfies your time constrictions but hope this helps.